# Распознание квадрата в двумерной матрице

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Сделал вот такой грид.

[image: the grid]

Просто матрица 8x8 из чисел (0, 1, 2, 3), на основе которой и заполняется канва.

```
map =   [
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,2,0,2,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,3,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        ];
```

Цвет меняется кликом над белым квадратом. Один клик — одна смена цвета по возрастающей: `0(#000) -> 1(#f00) -> 2(#0f0) -> 3(#00f) -> 0 ...`

Как определить, что после четырёх случаев изменения цвета пользователем, в матрице появился квадрат 2х2 в любом месте грида? Например, как на скрине:

[image: square]

*Очевидно, что после четырёх кликов квадрат можно собрать только из красных квадратов.*

Comment: Матрица это одномерный массив с нумерацией от 0 до N.... Следовательно квадарат это координата, вторая точка `+-1` а две других `+-N` и `+-N(+-1)` соответственно.....если соблюдается это условие - значит квадрат

Comment: Уточните, какой квадрат интересует: из не-нулей или из одинаковых цифр? Что происходит при клике – меняется цвет кликнутой ячейки, или, по каким-то правилам, и других ячеек тоже?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, одномерный? o_O

Comment: @Qwertiy  ну не надо придираться к словам....я вам не Stack.....`можно представить в виде одномерного массива`. Вам так легче будет?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ага, я уже удалённый ответ прочитал.

Comment: Тогда до N*N =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Самый простой алгоритм выделения квадрата 2х2 в заданной матрице может быть таким:

1. Начните обход матрицы с левого верхнего элемента и проверяйте *построчно* (это важно!), двигаясь слева на право. При достижении правого края строки, переходите на самый левый элемент следующей строки.
2. Если вы нашли элемент, значение которого равно единице, вы нашли левый верхний угол квадрата. Обозначим его координаты как `(X, Y)`.
3. Проверьте элементы с координатами `(X+1, Y+1)`, `(X, Y+1)`, `(X+1, Y)`. Если все они равны единице, то вы нашли квадрат. В противном случае, ваша матрица не содержит квадрата.
4. Если при достижении последнего элемента матрицы `(W, H)` вы так и не нашли ни одного элемента со значением равным единице, то ваша матрица не содержит единичных (*красных*) ячеек. Как следствие, она просто не может содержать в себе квадрата 2x2 из единиц.

**Замечение:** При проверке соседних элементов матрицы, координаты `X+1` и `Y+1` могут выходить за границы исходной матрицы. Проверять значения таких элементов не имеет смысла.

**UPD:** При желании, алгоритм можно оптимизировать, например так:

1. При первоначальном обходе матрицы проверять не каждый элемент строки а через один. Это поможет снизить количество проверок на `W / 2`.
2. Более того, можно проверять не каждую строку, а только через одну. Это позволит снизить количество проверок на `H / 2`.
3. Наложение условий 1 и 2 требует проверки найденного единичного элемента не только как левого верхнего, но и как любого углового. Если каждую из проверок начинать с противоположенного угла квадрата, то это увеличит количество проверок на `3` в худшем случае.

Оптимизированная версия алгоритма в худшем случае потребует выполнения `H * W / 4 + 6` проверок. Для матрицы 8х8 в худшем случае это всего 22 итерации.

Comment: при обходе от (0,0) к (w,h)  найденный элемент следует рассматривать только как левый верхний, и проверять соседей только вправо и вниз. Это ускорит обход.

Comment: Да, вы правы, изменил порядок проверок. Вообще, если всегда использовать строго определенные правила обхода массива, можно ограничиться всего одной проверкой.

Comment: Ну да, это логично. раз мы берем первый попавшийся на пути следования элемент, значит, как минимум выше и левее ничего уже нет @DmitriySimushev можно по сути 3,4,5 пункты вообще исключать

Comment: Да, значит левее и выше мы уже проверили все не-нули. Пп. 3,4,5 можно убирать. Потом, изменения, вроде бы, происходят по клику на ячейке, значит, стоит проверять её и соседей, а всё обходить, наверное, ни к чему.

Comment: Да, я как-то упустил этот момент с самого начала. Упростил алгоритм.

Comment: "замечание-2": проверять элементы с индексами `>=` длине стороны тоже не стоит.

Comment: @Sergiks, в случае с направленным обходом, координата `-1` не может получиться) А вот насчет превышения границ, вы правы

Answer (score 5):

В общем случае после каждого клика на точке необходимо проверить от 3 до 8 соседних точек (в зависимости от расположения исходной).

Алгоритм примерно такой (для jscript уже сами подгоните)

```
if ((map [x,y-1] + map[x-1,y-1] + map[x-1,y] == 3)
|| (map [x-1,y] + map[x-1,y+1] + map[x,y+1] == 3)
|| (map [x,y+1] + map[x+1,y+1] + map[x+1,y] == 3)
|| (map [x+1,y] + map[x+1,y-1] + map[x,y-1] == 3))
```

где x и y, координаты точки, на которой произошел клик.

Т.е. в вашем случае при клике на точку, указанную как А, проверяются точки, указанные как В.

```
map =   [
                [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,B,B,B,0,0,0,0],
                [0,B,А,B,0,0,0,0],
                [0,B,B,B,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
                ];
```

Comment: Идея ясна, однако в ячейках могут быть цифры от 0 до 3, так что три в сумме может получиться и когда не надо. Там скорее стоит поставить условие, что каждый из проверяемых элементов  `!= 0`.

Comment: @LittleTofu, условие `!= 0` не подойдет потому, что для точки A лежащей на границе, вы будете обращаться к элементу с индексом `-1`. Массивы в JavaScript это позволяют, но в этом случае возвращается значение `undefined`. В свою очередь, `undefined != 0` вернет `true`.

Answer (score 3):

По клику проверяем изменившуюся ячейку, т.к. она могла создать квадрат с соседями.

Сначала проверяем четыре диагональные от неё ячейки, и, если нашлись не пустые, то дополнительно проверяем смежные. Запустив сниппет, на цифрах можно кликать:

```js
var map = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
  ], 
  $out = $('#out'),
  $2x2 = $('#2x2'),
  colors = ['r','g','b']
;

function makeMatrix(row, y){ return '[' + row.map( makeCell.bind(null,y)).join(',') + ']';}
function makeCell(y, cell, x) { return '<span class="cell'+(cell>0?' '+colors[cell-1]:'')+'" data-x="'+x+'" data-y="'+y+'">' + cell + '</span>';}
$out.html( '[<br>' + map.map( makeMatrix).join(',<br>') + '<br>]');

$('.cell').on('click', function(){
  var $el = $(this).removeClass().addClass('cell')
     ,x = $el.data('x')
     ,y = $el.data('y')
  ;
  $el.text( map[y][x] = (map[y][x]+1)%4);
  if(map[y][x]>0) $el.addClass( colors[map[y][x]-1]);
  $2x2.text('');
  [-1,1].map( function(i){
    var xx = x + i;
    if(xx < 0  ||  xx > 7) return;
    [-1,1].map( function(j) {
      var yy = y + j;
      if(yy < 0  ||  yy > 7) return;
      if( map[yy][xx] == 0) return;
      if( map[yy][x] == 0  ||  map[y][xx] == 0) return;
      // found 2x2
      $2x2.text( "Found: " + x+',' +y +' : ' +xx+',' +yy);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#out {font-family:Courier New,monospace;font-size:12px}
.cell {background-color: #EEE; cursor:pointer}
.r {background-color: #F99}
.g {background-color: #3F3}
.b {background-color: #99F}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="out"></div>
<div id="2x2"></div>
```

Comment: Если запускать проверку каждый раз при клике, то после некоторого количества кликов будет эффективнее проверять один раз всю матрицу

Comment: Проверяется макс 4 варианта же при клике. Зачем всю?

Comment: Это я понимаю. При матрице 8х8, при худших случаях для обоих алгоритмов после 13 кликов, эффективнее проверять всю матрицу один раз)

Comment: Т.е. 13 кликов терпеть и ничего не проверять, а потом разом нагрянуть с инспекцией? =)  Я не знаю, какая там логика игры у ТС.

Comment: Я тоже не знаю. Просто это было небольшое замечание по эффективности алгоритмов =)

Comment: На самом деле, в худшем случае вашему алгоритму требуется не 4 проверки а 6. А раз так, то в худшем случае вам нужно выполнить 24 проверки на 4 клика. При этом, оптимизированный алгоритм поиска по всей матрице требует всего **22** проверки )))