# Реализация игры точки на canvas

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Делаю игру под названием точки на canvas.
 это ссылка на игру в вики:
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_(game)
 У меня есть проблема с рисовании полигона, кто-то может подсказать как реализовать это?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Документ без названия</title>
</head>

<body>

<canvas  id="my_canvas" width= 520px  height="520px" style="display:block; margin: 0 auto; background-image: url(2.png)"></canvas>
<h2 id="player1">0</h2>
<h2 id="player2">0</h2>
</body>
<script>


function draw()
{
    try
    {
        var elem = document.getElementById("my_canvas");
        var ctx = elem.getContext("2d");
        // Var
        var polygon = 520;                 //max pixel
        var max_points = 14;               //max points
        var pixel = 40;                    //size of point in pixel
        var counter = 0;                   // counter
        var n =14; var m =14;

        // Array
        var points = new Array();          // points
        var pointX = new Array();          // point for X
        var pointY = new Array();          // point for Y
        var pos_pt = new Array(n);         // value of every point
        for(var i =0; i<n;i++)
        {pos_pt[i] = new Array(m);}
        for(var i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for(var j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                pos_pt[i][j]= 0;
            }
        }
        // sing position of points
        for(var i =0 ;i < max_points; i++)
        {
            points[i] = pixel*i;
        }
        // drawing line
        for (var i = 0; i <= polygon; i = i + pixel)
        {
            //draw X line
            ctx.moveTo(0, i);
            ctx.lineTo(polygon, i);
            ctx.stroke();
            // draw Y line
            ctx.moveTo(i, 0);
            ctx.lineTo(i, polygon);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        //drawing points massive points[i][j]
        for(var i = 0 ; i<max_points;i++)
        {
            for(var j = 0 ; j<max_points;j++)
            {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(points[i],points[j],5,0,2*Math.PI);
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        }
        // drawing on click
         ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event)
        {
            var mouseX = event.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
            var mouseY = event.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;
            var interval = 7;
            for (var i = 0; i < max_points; i++)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < max_points; j++)
                {
                    if(mouseX < (i*pixel)+interval && mouseX > (i*pixel)-interval && mouseY < (j*pixel)+interval && mouseY>(j*pixel)-interval)
                    {
                        ctx.beginPath();

                        if(counter % 2 == 0 && pos_pt[i][j] != 2 && pos_pt[i][j] != 1)
                        {
                            ctx.arc(points[i],points[j],12,0,2*Math.PI);
                            ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
                            ctx.fill();
                            ctx.stroke();
                            counter++;
                            pos_pt[i][j] =1;
                            ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
                            ctx.font ="16px serif";
                            pointX.push(i);
                            pointY.push(j);
                            ctx.fillText(pos_pt[i][j],points[i]-3.5,points[j]+3.5);
                                                    }
                        else if(counter % 2 != 0 && pos_pt[i][j] != 2 && pos_pt[i][j] != 1)
                        {
                            ctx.arc(points[i],points[j],12,0,2*Math.PI);
                            ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
                            ctx.fill();
                            ctx.stroke();
                            counter++;
                            pos_pt[i][j] = 2;
                            ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
                            ctx.font ="16px serif";
                            ctx.fillText(pos_pt[i][j],points[i]-3.5,points[j]+3.5);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert("the something go wrong");
                        }
                        // drawing blue polygon
                        var player = pos_pt[i][j];
                        console.log(player);
                        if(pos_pt[i][j]==1)
                        {
                            if(player +1 == 2 && player -1 == 2)
                            {
                                console.log("ok");
                            }
                        }
                        console.log(i,j,pos_pt[i][j]);
                        console.log(i+1,j,pos_pt[i+1][j]);
                        console.log(i-1,j,pos_pt[i-1][j]);
                        console.log(i,j+1,pos_pt[i][j+1]);
                        console.log(i,j-1,pos_pt[i][j-1]);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        //end of try
    }
    catch (e)                               //error
    {
        alert("the something go wrong");
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load',function(event){
   draw();
});
</script>

</html>















<!--
ctx.beginPath();
                                ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,255,0.5)";
                                for (var m = 0; m < 3; m++) {
                                    console.log(pointX[m]);
                                    ctx.moveTo(pointX[m] * pixel, pointY[m] * pixel);
                                    ctx.lineTo(pointX[m + 2] * pixel, pointY[m + 2] * pixel);
                                    ctx.lineTo(pointX[m + 1] * pixel, pointY[m + 1] * pixel);
                                    ctx.lineTo(pointX[0] * pixel, pointY[0] * pixel);
                                }
                                                            ctx.closePath();
                            ctx.fill();
```

заранее спасибо

Comment: а что не так с закомментированным кодом, который как раз и рисует полигон?

Comment: @Grundy Думаю, ТС хочет сказать, что не знает как вычислить что уже пора рисовать полигон и как его правильно нарисовать с учетом того, что не просто должен рисоваться полигон между соседними точками, а только между теми, которые сами не находятся в полигоне уже и т.д....... А т.к. поле может быть большим, то вычислить что в конкретный момент должно объединиться в полигон - сложновато...

Comment: пока оствлю это http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488670/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5   может быть поможет.... а пока надо подумать еще

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, стоило бы это в самом вопросе указать :-)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, у меня там идет индексация точек
синие == 1
красные == 2
пустое место == 0

Comment: Не стоит создавать полностью дублирующие вопросы