# Алгоритм жука игра точки на javascript

Tags: javascript, html, алгоритм, html5, canvas

Есть игра по ссылке:

[Реализация игры точки на canvas](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/515328/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-canvas)

Помогите пожалуйста разработать рисование полигона относительно точек.