# Алгоритм замкнутого контура

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

У меня есть игра "точки". C каждым ходом у меня изменяется значение в двумерном массиве. Можете подсказать как найти все замкнутые контура?
[ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/515328](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/515328/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-canvas)

Comment: Flood-fill в помощь